# Add column to DataFrame and assign number to each row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following table

| Father | Son | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | Harry | 1999 |
| James | Alfi | 2001 |
| Corey | Kyle | 2003 |

I would like to add a fourth column that makes the table look like below. It's supposed to show which child of each father was born first, second, third, and so on. How can I do that?

| Father | Son | Year | Child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Harry | 1999 | 1 |
| James | Alfi | 2001 | 2 |
| Corey | Kyle | 2003 | 1 |

Comment: Have a look at `groupby` and `cumsum` functions in pandas.

Comment: did you write any code or if yes please post it I don't want to be mean or something but stack overflow  is not a platform of "here is what I want to do code it for me" here is a suggestion of what a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) can look like.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it. using cumcount

```
# groupby Father and take a cumcount, offsetted by 1
df['Child']=df.groupby(['Father'])['Son'].cumcount()+1
df
```

```
    Father  Son     Year    Child
0   James   Harry   1999    1
1   James   Alfi    2001    2
2   Corey   Kyle    2003    1
```

it assumes that DF is sorted by Father and Year. if not, then

```
df['Child']=df.sort_values(['Father','Year']).groupby(['Father'] )['Son'].cumcount()+1
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of solving this using `groupby` and `cumsum` functions.
This assumes that the rows are ordered so that the younger sibling is always below their elder brother and all children of the same father are in a continuous pack of rows.

Assume we have the following setup

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Father': ['James', 'James', 'Corey'], 
                   'Son': ['Harry', 'Alfi', 'Kyle'], 
                   'Year': [1999, 2001, 2003]})
```

then here is the trick we group the siblings with the same father into a groupby object and then compute the cumulative sum of ones to assign a sequential number to each row.

```
df['temp_column'] = 1
df['Child'] = df.groupby('Father')['temp_column'].cumsum()
df.drop(columns='temp_column')
```

The result would look like this

```
  Father    Son  Year  Child
0  James  Harry  1999      1
1  James   Alfi  2001      2
2  Corey   Kyle  2003      1
```

Now to make the solution more general consider reordering the rows to satisfy the preconditions before applying the solution and then if necessary restore the dataframe to the original order.